# Can anyone help with “Malformed entry 9 in list file”

Tags: files, error-handling, source, xfce4-terminal

I hate to say it but, I’m extremely new to all of this and looks to me like I’ve hit a simple roadblock but I’m confused as to how I should fix this...

so my issue is pretty much any command I run leads to the error listed below, with the first line being an example of an attempted command...

Sudo apt-get update

E: Malformed entry 9 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)

E:The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: This will get closed as a duplicate as it gets asked all the time. The answer is that you have a bad line 9 in your /etc/apt/sources.list file, just like it says. If you want specific help, edit your question and add the contents of that file.

Comment: You already asked this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304573/how-can-i-fix-malformed-entry-9-in-list-file) and were referred to previous answers. Have you tried applying them? if so, in what way did they not work for you?

Comment: Someone with `sudo` rights on your machine, has edited the file listed in the error message and introduced an error in line 9 of that file. The error message is pretty helpful (*in my opinion*) giving pretty clear issues on where the error is (the line is malformed for a sources file). By looking at the timestamp of the file you'll see it was changed. As per prior comments, as we cannot see the file, we can't help you further.